# Getting last-child of a div in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors

Is there another way to get the last child of a div element other than using `div:last-child`, which does not work in IE8 at least?

Comment: Do you want CSS or javascript.  It's impossible in CSS alone.

Comment: Are you using jQuery per chance?

Comment: "p:last-child" will get the last paragraph that is a child of your selector

Comment: If your having trouble using this syntax in jquery provide your exact code in the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the last-child selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293369/using-the-last-child-selector)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In jQuery it's easy:

```
$("div :last-child")
```

In pure CSS it can't be done.

Otherwise you're stuck with traversing the DOM in Javascript.

Also note the difference:

- `"div :last-child"`: every last child of a div; and
- `"div:last-child"`: every div that **is** a last child.

Comment: Nice answer, especially explaining the difference in selectors.

Comment: What do you mean by "In pure CSS it can't be done"? Do you mean "not every browser supports it" or something else?

Comment: :last-child is a CSS3 selector so there are only a few browsers that support it. Without it you can't select the last child (with only CSS).

Comment: The only problem with your answer is it does not address what to do when he has already selected the parent element, e.g. he is chaining:
$(".mydiv").dostuff().(get the last child somehow).dochildstuff().  I believe two methods that work are .children().last() and probably .children(":last-child")

Comment: @MikeJ `$(".mydiv").doStuff().children().eq(-1).doChildStuff()` is probably the most elegant.

Answer (score 21):

Unfortunately, I know not a way to do this in CSS without using :last-child, which (as you stated) fails in IE.

If you're talking about javascript, then it's possible using Node.lastChild:

```
var div = document.getElementById("mydiv");
var lastChild = div.lastChild;
```

Answer (score 6):

Use jQuery to find the appropriate elements: `$("div:last-child").addClass("last-child");`

Then use CSS to specify the presentation: `div .last-child { /* your rules */ }`

Answer (score 4):

You can assign a class 'last' programmatically and select that one or use javascript. You might also have a shot by using some of Microsofts IE only css script thingies. But I do not know much about them, also do not consider that as an option.

Comment: +1, I agree. It's silly to depend on JavaScript to do this for you. Just be pragmatic and add a class="last" to the last element. It takes two seconds and will work everywhere. You can easily take it out and use the last-child CSS selector in a few years when it's widely supported.

Answer (score 3):

I do this with pure JavaScript by looping back through the nodes from the lastChild of the target element. If there is whitespace in your HTML, the lastChild may be a text node, so we loop until we find an element node (node type 1) or until we run out of nodes (previousSibling will return null).

For example, to find the last element in a page, I loop back from the lastChild of the body:

```
var targetElement = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],
    lastChildElement = targetElement.lastChild;

while (lastChildElement && lastChildElement.nodeType !== 1) {
    lastChildElement = lastChildElement.previousSibling;
}

if (lastChildElement) {
    // Do something
}
```

If there is no element inside the body, lastChildElement will exit this loop as null.

Answer (score 2):

There are some cases in which you definitely don't want to use $("div:last-child") out of the box. One important thing to note is that this won't cater for changes to the DOM after that call - e.g. if a new element is added as the last child, you'll need to update things. It's not just a case of repeating the earlier call, either; you'll need to reverse the initial call on the previous last child.

If you're doing anything vaguely dynamic, be wary of this. the CSS pseudo-class is *definitely* the superior solution, it just has a horrible lack of support in IE. If your design can cope with the loss of last-child support in IE, and you're using progressive enrichment, I'd highly recommend the CSS approach over JS.

Answer (score 1):

**Fast Forward >> 4 years later (2013)**
It is now possible with CSS v3 (CSS3) and is supported by all major browsers (with IE being >= version 9).
If you travel back in time with **IE <= version 8**, then **jQuery version < 1.x** will sort you out (just as the other answers have pointed out).
Read more http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp

Answer (score -1):

```
var divs = $("id").getElementsByTagName('div');
var lastChild = divs[divs.length-1];
```