# Using the last-child selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

My goal is to apply the CSS on the last `li`, but it doesn't do that.

```css
#refundReasonMenu #nav li:last-child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
}
```

```html
<div id="refundReasonMenu">
     <ul id="nav">
      <li><a id="abc" href="#">abcde</a></li>
      <li><a id="def" href="#">xyz</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

How can I select *only* the last child?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

The `:last-child` pseudoclass still cannot be reliably used across browsers.  In particular, Internet Explorer versions < 9, and Safari < 3.2 definitely [don't support it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:last-child#Browser_compatibility), although Internet Explorer 7 and Safari 3.2  *do* support `:first-child`, curiously.

Your best bet is to explicitly add a `last-child` (or similar) class to that item, and apply `li.last-child` instead.

Comment: That can also be what causes it, yeah :)

Comment: IIRC, IE7 doesn't support it, and first-child is sketchy.  I'd go with this method of adding your own class, it's much more reliable.

Comment: I tested the above on Safari 4 and it worked ok. But support in general is variable, so you'll need to try something else.

Comment: IE8 doesn't support `:last-child` either. And it's not *that* curious. `:first-child` is a CSS2 pseudo-class, `:last-child` a CSS3 pseudo-class.

Comment: last-child works in all the modern browsers, which means, of course, it does not work in any version of IE.

Comment: fyi, IE **9** [supports `:last-child`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#pseudoclasses).

Comment: @mercator It's curious that :first-child was implement in CSS2 but :last-child was left until CSS3 ... seems pretty obvious to add them at the same time.

Comment: IE7 refuses to recognize other bastard children

Comment: @Cobby It's a parsing thing. :first-child is easier to implement because it doesn't require a look-ahead. See http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors

Comment: @Tamlyn I didn't realise ease of implementation affected spec writing :P That's a nice article though, thanks!

Comment: Wow... checking the edit time vs comment posts.. I would think programmers here know what < 9 means......

Answer (score 76):

Another solution that might work for you is to reverse the relationship. So you would set the border for all list items. You would then use first-child to eliminate the border for the first item. The first-child is statically supported in all browsers (meaning it can't be added dynamically through other code, but first-child is a CSS2 selector, whereas last-child was added in the CSS3 specification)

Note: This only works the way you intended if you only have 2 items in the list like your example. Any 3rd item and on will have borders applied to them.

Comment: +1 for out of the box thinking :-) I just converted my last-child elements to first-child and changed by border-right to border-left for menu separators. Now IE8 likes my css.

Answer (score 43):

If you think you can use Javascript, then since jQuery support `last-child`, you can use jQuery's css method and the good thing it will support almost all the browsers

**Example Code:**

```
$(function(){
   $("#nav li:last-child").css("border-bottom","1px solid #b5b5b5")
})
```

You can find more info about here : http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2

Comment: Wayyy better to do something like `$("#nav li:last-child").addClass('last-child')` so you can keep your styling in your stylesheets.

Comment: This is cleaner than the first solution since it is handled automatically. But I agree with jason, too.

Comment: Actually, IE7 doesn't load a class that has both `div:last-child` and `div.last-child`. It appears that it considers the `:last-child` syntax to be invalid and any class with that pseudo-selector won't be applied.

Comment: @Josh M.: That's correct and expected behavior. *Quite* unfortunate, I should say. You'd have to duplicate the rule.

Answer (score 19):

If the number of list items is fixed you can use the adjacent selector, e.g. if you only have three `<li>` elements, you can select the last `<li>` with:

```css
    li+li+li {
        color: red;
        font-size: 170%;
    }
```

```html
 <ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Last</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Your selector is wrong. `li + #nav li` selects `li` inside `#nav` that comes after `li`. Your selector should simply be `#nav li + li + li`.

Comment: That's nifty. Works fine in IE8, however not in IE7.

Answer (score 13):

If you find yourself frequently wanting CSS3 selectors, you can always use the selectivizr library on your site:

http://selectivizr.com/

It's a JS script that adds support for almost all of the CSS3 selectors to browsers that wouldn't otherwise support them.

Throw it into your `<head>` tag with an IE conditional:

```
<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
  <script src="/js/selectivizr-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 3):

last-child pseudo class does not work in ***IE***

[CSS Compatibility and Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28VS.85%29.aspx)

[IE7 CSS Selectors: How they fail](http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/05/ie7-css-selectors-how-they-fail/)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using a class you could use a detailed list, setting the child dt elements to have one style and the child dd elements to have another. Your example would become:

```
#refundReasonMenu #nav li:dd
{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="refundReasonMenu">
  <dl id="nav">
        <dt><a id="abc" href="#">abcde</a></dt>
        <dd><a id="def" href="#">xyz</a></dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

Neither method is better than the other and it is just down to personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is using the last-child selector in jQuery and then use the .css() method.  Be weary though because some people are still in the stone age using JavaScript disabled browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Why not apply the border to the bottom of the UL?

```
#refundReasonMenu #nav ul
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
}
```

Comment: If you have `padding-bottom` on the `<ul>` element or `margin-bottom` on the last `<li>` element, this will not have the desired placement of right underneath the last `<li>` element. Otherwise, this is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are floating the elements you can reverse the order

i.e. `float: right;` instead of `float: left;`

And then use this method to select the first-child of a class.

```
/* 1: Apply style to ALL instances */
#header .some-class {
  padding-right: 0;
}
/* 2: Remove style from ALL instances except FIRST instance */
#header .some-class~.some-class {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

This is actually applying the class to the LAST instance only because it's now in reversed order.

Here is a working example for you:

```
<!doctype html>
<head><title>CSS Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
.some-class { margin: 0; padding: 0 20px; list-style-type: square; }
.lfloat { float: left; display: block; }
.rfloat { float: right; display: block; }
/* apply style to last instance only */
#header .some-class {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding-right: 0;
}
#header .some-class~.some-class {
  border: 0;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
  <img src="some_image" title="Logo" class="lfloat no-border"/>
  <ul class="some-class rfloat">
    <li>List 1-1</li>
    <li>List 1-2</li>
    <li>List 1-3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="some-class rfloat">
    <li>List 2-1</li>
    <li>List 2-2</li>
    <li>List 2-3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="some-class rfloat">
    <li>List 3-1</li>
    <li>List 3-2</li>
    <li>List 3-3</li>
  </ul>
  <img src="some_other_img" title="Icon" class="rfloat no-border"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

It's hard to say without seeing the rest of your CSS, but try adding `!important` in front of the border color, to make it like so:

```
#refundReasonMenu #nav li:last-child
{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b5b5b5 !important;
}
```