# how to center UL in my page?

Tags: css, html-lists

we have a problem of making the ul-ed blocks of buttons on the top of the page ideal to the center.

here is the link.

[nick.georates.net/selectcountry.html](http://nick.georates.net/selectcountry.html)

can you give a hint how in the css adjust so that the buttons will be in the middle for any resolution of the page????

thanks beforehand

Comment: the ul with the class = "shortcut-buttons-set" inherits a padding-left:40px; try to overwrite that in the "shortcut-buttons-set" class

Comment: @thedev: This is the right answer, please post it as an answer and I will vote you up. @DR.GEWA: The element from which the padding is inherited is #main-content in style.css line 236.

Comment: @DR GEWA  glad to be of assistance... good luck with your project  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the ul with the class = "shortcut-buttons-set" inherits a padding-left:40px; try to overwrite that in the "shortcut-buttons-set" class

Comment: Voted up, as said in comment of the question. :)

Comment: @Bazzz 6 months later accepted as the right answer ... that's fast ... good thing the apocalypse didn't come today

Answer (score 0):

As you have five `<li>` you can set their width as 20%, whith `margin:auto` links will appear center.

```
li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:20%;
    float:left;
}
a {
    width:103px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: actually I don't want li-s to be with percent as I think for big resolutions the buttons will be ugly big... or?

Comment: Buttons are only <a> tags, <li> width won't affect them. You will just have more space between them.

Answer (score 0):

Give the `ul` element a width - in this case it would be 600px, as you have 5 buttons * 105px width and 15px margin for each button. Removing the padding set on the `ul` and the left and right values set on the `li`, and give the `ul` element this style:

```
.shortcut-buttons-set {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 600px;
}

ul.shortcut-buttons-set li {
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
    padding: 0 !important;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Additionally, you'll want to use `:last-child` to remove the last 15px margin, so that the buttons are *perfectly* aligned.

```
.shortcut-buttons-set li:last-child {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Taking this into account, the width for the `ul` should now be 585px.

Comment: The :last-child pseudo-class is not compatible will all browser as detailed in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293369/using-last-child-in-css)

Comment: AS usual, if you need as much support as possible you can switch `margin-right` to `margin-left` and use `:first-child`. Of course that *still* won't work with IE6, so you can always add a class instead.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your UL element inside a DIV with a width of 100%

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <ul class="shortcut-buttons-set">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>       
     </ul>
</div>
```

Apply this CSS to UL

```
.shortcut-buttons-set{
display:inline-block;
list-style:none outside none;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
}
```

and remove the property left:25% and right:25% to your LI element.

```
ul.shortcut-buttons-set li{
background:none repeat scroll 0 50% transparent;
float:left;
font-weight:bold;
***left:25%;***
margin:0 15px 0 0;
padding:0 !important;
position:relative;
***right:25%;***
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Why width:100% for a block element?