# How to apply spacing between divs without having an excess at the right or the left?

Tags: css

This is one of the common issues i face and i end up having nasty additional spacer markup to avoid having a margin in the right or the left ( also at the top or the bottom if it's a vertical menu ).

Is there a clean css way to avoid applying the margin for the last element?

---

[image]

Comment: This irks me no end as well. I usually end up adding a `.last` class to the last item. You could also see about using `last-child`, should be supported on modern browsers though : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293369/using-last-child-in-css

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `:not(:last-child)`.

```
.box:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Or,

```
.box:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.box:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Or,

```
.box {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.box:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Or,

```
.box {
    margin: 0 5px;
}

.box:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.box:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

---

Compatibility:

- CSS2 [`:not`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t37) pseudo-class
- CSS2 [`:first-child`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t17) pseudo class
- CSS3 [`:last-child`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t35) pseudo class

Comment: Thanks that looks clean, The real question is: is it supported by major browsers? Thanks again.

Comment: @David which versions of IE do you care about?

Comment: @Harpyon, that will require another selector for `.box` using the `not()` means only using one. Although if other CSS properties are being set it would be more efficient to drop the `not()`.

Comment: It's funny, you posted almost every variation except the one that should actually be used (thanks to IE7/8). Still, +1

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
.box {
    margin-left: 20px
}
.box:first-child {
    margin-left: 0
}
```

This is better than using `:last-child` (from [CSS 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#last-child-pseudo)), because that's not supported in IE7/8, whereas `:first-child` (from [CSS 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#first-child)) is.

Answer (score 1):

i guess you can try this one, http://jsfiddle.net/yuliantoadi/g98Wq/

html :

```
<div class="container">
<div class="box">
    box 1
</div>
<div class="box">
    box 2
</div>
<div class="box">
    box 3
</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.box{
    width:32%;
    float:left;
    background:red;
    margin-left:2%;
}
.container {
    background:blue;
    padding:2%;
}
.container .box:first-child{
    margin-left:0;
}
```

is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Quirks Mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) :last-child isn't supported in IE6/7/8 so an alternative could be to apply another class to the last element and then just override the margin in the CSS.