# Please tel me last-child alternate for IE 7

Tags: css

Please tel me last-child alternate for IE 7,any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

As described in this thread: [Using the last-child selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293369/using-last-child-in-css). You shouldn't use `last-child` as it is not cross-browser compatible.

The solution given is to **give a class to your last element** so you can style it.

Btw, the W3C specification of CSS2.0 did not validate the use of `last-child` even if some browser support it so it can be un-supported in further versions.

Comment: thanks for reply,But sir , as my all  my LI are genric not static,i have solved this by jquery:
 jQuery('.itemList .news-body-div:last').css('border','none');
           });

Comment: @Mehmood Khan: i'm glad you found a solution to your issue. To be full "stackoverflow-compliant", you can post your comment as an answer and accept it. This is great for avoiding to leave questions unanswered.