# Normalize perceived padding on an element with unknown children

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I have a `<div>` styled like a box:

```
.box {
    border:2px solid #ccc;
    background:#eee;   
    padding:1em;
    margin:1em;
}
```

In this box, there could be any number of any type of child elements in any order:

```
<div class="box">
    <h3>Howzit goin</h3>
    <p>Here comes a list:</p>
    <ul>
        <li>I don't know what</li>
        <li>this box will contain</li>
        <li>but it could be anything</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Most or all of the child elements inherit bottom margin of various lengths from the base typography stylesheet:

```
/* Example global typography */
p {margin:0 0 1.5em;}
ul {margin:0 0 2.5em;}
```

Which produces output like this:

[image]

...but we want to normalize the "padding" of the box so that it appears equal on all sides:

[image]

- `.box :last-child` would be too easy, this has to work in at least IE8 as well as 
  modern browsers (but it could be used in conjunction with an IE-only method).
- I don't want to use extra markup or javascript.

Is there any other CSS trick I can use to get the output I want?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yuXcH/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293369/using-last-child-in-css), even if it's about 2 years old, there's no "easy" way to do this in IE8 (the other thread is just about IE6/7, but things haven't changed - IE8 doesn't support `:last-child` either).

The best way, in my opinion, is to manually add a class `last-child` to your last child so you can do:

```
.box .last-child{ margin-bottom: 0; }
```

The alternative is using javascript, which is easier if you have a lot of boxes. With [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), it would just look like this:

```
$(function(){
  $(".box :last-child").css("margin-bottom","0");
})
```

The only "pure CSS" solution I can think of is changing all of your padding/margins to always result in a box with same padding on all sides like Lollero suggested, but this will, compared to your previous solution, result in different margins between the elements inside of the box.

Comment: The hitch is, this is coming from a WYSIWYG where I can't expect the poor folks to add CSS classes, they just highlight the text and click "make it a box". I think you are probably right - there's no easy way to do it. I will probably add a `.last-child` class with js, but it won't show up in the WYSIWYG unfortunately... Can't wait to be rid of IE8. Will probably accept this answer - I don't have high hopes for another solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably compensate the extra space by having padding or margin in both top and bottom.

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/yuXcH/2/

Also some padding change in top and/or bottom of the parent element can be used.

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/yuXcH/3/

Comment: #1 is not an option because firstly - the output is different, and I'd have to select `.box p, .box ul, .box ol, .box blockquote {}` etc. to change it, otherwise it will affect *all* the elements and make for poor typography on the rest of the page. #2 will not work because it doesn't normalize the bottom padding, it defers it to the last child which means it could still be any value including `0`.

Comment: @WesleyMurch I have no idea what you want.