# first-child and last-child with IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors

I have some css for adjusting things in my table.

Here it is:

```
.editor td:first-child
{
    width: 150px; 
}

.editor td:last-child input,
.editor td:last-child textarea
{
    width: 500px;
    padding: 3px 5px 5px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC; 
}
```

It works with Firefox, Safari and Chrome but not (at this time) with IE8.

I know the problem comes from the first-child and last-child but I'm not an expert.

Any idea how I can fixt it?

PS: I added `<!doctype html>` on top of my html document but nothing changed.

Comment: IE8 does not support `:last-child` (although I believe it does support `:first-child`, as that was in the CSS 2.1 spec, whereas `:last-child` was in CSS 3).

Comment: Maybe we can trick by selecting all others td than :first-child ? Any idea? So we can get both selections...?

Comment: @Bronzato: "all other than :first-child" is not the same as ":last-child", unless your table only has two columns.

Comment: Yes my table contains only two columns :)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

If your table is only 2 columns across, you can easily reach the second `td` with the adjacent sibling selector, which IE8 does support along with `:first-child`:

```
.editor td:first-child
{
    width: 150px; 
}

.editor td:first-child + td input,
.editor td:first-child + td textarea
{
    width: 500px;
    padding: 3px 5px 5px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC; 
}
```

Otherwise, you'll have to use a JS selector library like jQuery, or manually add a class to the last `td`, [as suggested by James Allardice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8840911/106224).

Comment: Nice one... never thought of that!

Comment: +1 great solution. thank you. ( `except myne is  .rowClose > td+td+td+td+td+td+td` ) http://i.stack.imgur.com/08jym.jpg

Comment: Gamn you IE8. Looks like there's no other way, so let's create a thousand class="last_child".

Answer (score 34):

Since `:last-child` is a CSS3 pseudo-class, it is not supported in IE8. I believe `:first-child` is supported, as it's defined in the CSS2.1 specification.

One possible solution is to simply give the last child a class name and style that class.

Another would be to use JavaScript. jQuery makes this particularly easy as it provides a [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) pseudo-class which should work in IE8. Unfortunately, that could result in a flash of unstyled content while the DOM loads.

Comment: jQ does work nicely, just have to add to my global .js <link>    `$(".bordTL th:last-child").css("border-right","1px solid black");` It is a small clean up so being delayed a second isn't egregious.

Comment: Just saw `$("#nav li:last-child").addClass('last-child')` (thank you jason http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293369/using-last-child-in-css)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to carry on using CSS3 selectors but need to support older browsers I would suggest using a polyfill such as [Selectivizr.js](http://selectivizr.com/)