# Make last element in horizontal list stretch to remaining space?

Tags: css, layout, compass-sass

## Existing code

- `index.html`:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="stylesheets/index.css" rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <ul>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
    <li><input /></li>
  </ul>
  ```
- `index.scss` (without stretching):

  ```
  @import "compass/reset";
  @import "compass/typography/lists/horizontal-list";

  body {
    background: darkgray;
  }

  ul {
    width: 100%;
    background: lightgray;
    @include horizontal-list;
  }
  ```

## Question

*What is an elegant way to make the last element take up the remaining
 horizontal space?*

Details:

- See image below for desired output.
- Adaption of HTML code is OK, as long as it remains semantically clear.
- The solution should work in the latest Firefox, in the latest Chrome, and
  in IE8-11 (JavaScript shim, if needed, is acceptable).

[image: Desired output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one solution with only css.

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Bar</li>
  <li class="last"><input type="text" /></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li { float: left; list-style: none; }
ul li.last { float: none; display: block; overflow: hidden; }
ul li input { width: 100%; border: 0; box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #000; }
```

Demo:

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
ul li { float: left; list-style: none; }
ul li.last { float: none; display: block; overflow: hidden; }
ul li input { width: 100%; border: 0; box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #000; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Bar</li>
    <li class="last"><input type="text" /></li>
</ul>
```

([Also on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uKJUw/))

It should be supported by IE7+

Comment: Thanks! The last `li` takes up the remaining space, and the `input` sets width relative to the surround block element, which is the `li`.

Comment: It would be great if you could add the HTML from the fiddle to your answer. Otherwise, I noticed, it's incomplete.

Comment: Don't see the point since it differs with only one class, that can be added as static or dynamic(with js) but that wasn't the point of the question... But it's added...

Comment: Thanks! People copy and paste code. [Answering guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) point out that a *"target site [can be] unreachable or [go] permanently offline"*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:table-cell` ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/css-table)):

```
ul {
    width: 100%;
    background: lightgray;
}

li{
    display:table-cell;
}

ul>li:last-child, ul>li:last-child>input{
    width:100%;
}

ul>li:last-child>input{
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    background:red;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/vE4vK/)

However, `:last-child` is not supporter in IE8 so you'll need to target the last child with JavaScript or [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840802/first-child-and-last-child-with-ie8).