# How to keep 3 li items with 33.3% + margin-right on the same row? Border-box?

Tags: html, css, border-box

I have 3 li items - each with a width of 33.3%. Im trying to create a `margin-right` gap between each `<li>` - however the extra margin makes the total `<li>` width exceed 100% and break down on a new line.

Would I be able to sort this with some border-box approach? Tried to apply it globally, with no luck.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbazaN

```
html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.content {
  width: 700px;
  background: gray;
  padding: 20px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the [Calc function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

```
ul li {
    float: left;
    width: calc(33.3% - 20px);/*add this*/
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    background: blue;
}
```

Here you are

```css
html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.content {
  width: 700px;
  background: gray;
  padding: 20px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  width: calc(33.3% - 20px);
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

think about adding prefix or using [prefixfree](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) from lea verou.

**Update:**

To remove the margin on every third list item inside in your unordered lists you will need the [not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot) and [nth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child) selectors `ul li:not(:nth-child(3n+3))`

```
ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  /*margin: 0 20px 0 0;*/
  background: blue;
}
ul li:not(:nth-child(3n+3)){margin: 0 20px 0 0;}
```

live demo

```css
html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.content {
  width: 700px;
  background: gray;
  padding: 20px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  width: calc(33.3% - 20px);
  /*margin: 0 20px 0 0;*/
  background: blue;
}
ul li:not(:nth-child(3n+3)){margin: 0 20px 0 0}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

or write it and then overwrite it to avoid the not selector like this

```
ul li {
  float: left;
  width: calc(33.3% - 20px);
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  background: blue;
}
ul li:nth-child(3n+3){margin: 0 0px 0 0}
```

Comment: Cheers - thats pretty cool - didnt know about calc. How would I go about not having margin-right on every third item? So margin right would only be apploed to the two first li's?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support old browsers like IE8 you can use this method by doing little math.

In your case you have 3 items and you need to add margin right 20px for first two items that's total 40px .

Now deduct this value from the container ( will be 660px ) then divide it on the number of items,

(660/3 = 220px) width for each item, final step we need to get the percentage of item width = new item width / old container width [ 220/700 = .314286 (**31.429%**) ].

And finally we well remove margin right from the last items by adding class to it or use this one

`ul li + li + li { margin-right: 0 }` because IE8 and lower doesn't support last-child selector

In the end your code would be :

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.content {
  width: 700px;
  background: gray;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 31.429%;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  background: blue;
}

ul li+li+li {
  margin-right:0
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Reference: [Alternative for nth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16175273/5683483) , [first child and last child for IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8840911/5683483) , [Can i use](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)