# css pseudo class last-child issue

Tags: html, css

I am facing an issue when using the `:last-child` pseudo selector.

**I have the following markup:**

```
   <div class="apply_container">
        <form class="margin">
            <div class="apply_inn border">
                <span>Tell me why you want the job?</span>
            </div>
            <div class="apply_inn">
                <span>Some other details</span>
            </div>
            <div class="apply_inn location">
                <span>Apply at a particular location</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-actions">
                <button type="submit" class="pull-right btn btn-info">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**And apply these styles:**

```
.apply_container .apply_inn {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #E6E6E6;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 18px 0;
    width: 790px;
}

.apply_container .apply_inn:last-child {
    border:none;
}
```

My goal is to prevent the last `div.apply_inn` from being styled with a `bottom-border` like the rest of the `div.apply_inn`s.  The style does not seem to get applied.  Can anyone explain what is happening?

Here is the original [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QSeU2/) of my problem.  As well as a [simplified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hz2c5/) demonstrating the issue.

Comment: i dont see any borders. where are they.

Comment: it was is very light color changed color to red http://jsfiddle.net/QSeU2/1/

Comment: you seem to have something wrong with tags. some of them show red. make sure you close them right

Comment: @btevfik- its not possible due to - I copied it from firebug, and also main thing is, coded with HAML. so thats why all tags must be closed..!! :)

Comment: @btevfik: That's an issue with jsFiddle's highlighting treating void elements incorrectly (thinking they're not closed). It's valid HTML as far as I can see.

Comment: @Chandrakant Thanks for asking this question, I fought like hell to figure out the issue, but I definitely learned something.

Comment: @Kevin Actually I want to say thanks to you, for edit ..thnax alot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `div` with class `.apply_inn` is not the `last-child` within its parent.  The CSS `last-child` pseudo-class operates as follows:

> The :last-child CSS pseudo-class represents any element that is the
>   last child element of its parent.

When ready very literally, it will only apply to an element that is the last child within its parent.  It does not take into consideration the context you (mentally) create when you add the additional class selectors to it.

When applying the pseudo-class the browser doesn't understand the context created by the selector.  Basically, its checking that the element matches the selector `.apply_container .apply_inn`, then asking the question, "Is this the last child within the parent?".  It asks this question without any consideration of the aforementioned selector.  In your case, the answer is no since there is another div after the last `div.apply_inn`.

In your example, the div with the class `form-actions` is actually the last child.

Comment: The same can be said for each part of a compound selector. `div` = "Is this a `div`?", `.apply_inn` = "Does this have a class `apply_inn`?", `:last-child` = "Is this the last child of its parent?" The element has to match all of these conditions, but independently of every other condition.

Comment: @BoltClock Great supplementing info!  From a theoretical perspective, CSS boils down to a bunch of questions being asked by the browser.  I'm guessing mastering CSS is all about learning the specifics of the questions the browser is asking/answering.

Answer (score 2):

You can only use the `last-child` selector if it is the last child of it's parent container - although it was the last child with that class name it wasn't the last child of the container

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:last-child

Here is a fiddle showing your code with the last child style applied

http://jsfiddle.net/QSeU2/7/

Comment: Yes. There isn't a way to select the last element with the class name so one has to rely on workarounds such as those listed in the other answers.

Comment: the div with `apply_inn` is the first element of it's parent  container (`margin`)

Comment: Ohh ok..Now Resolved all puzzles regarding last and first child, Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 0):

target for `border-top` and remove the `first-child`'s `border-top`

http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/QSeU2/6/

last-child doesn't work.

Comment: yea it's good solution, I appreciate, but I'm trying to find out the reason - why last-child is not working, always this thing happens with me :)

Comment: The reason is because the last `.apply_inn` is not the last child. There is another element without that class after the last one.

Comment: @BoltClock- I did't getting you- in .apply_container div, number of .apply_inn is approx 5-6, and I want to select last one from those 5-6.

Comment: @Chandrakant: Yes but that last one has another element after it so it's not the last child.

Comment: @BoltClock :last-child is used to select the last element that matches the preceding selector. So in this case, it should match the last div with the .apply_in class.

Comment: @Vimal Stan: Um, no. I'm not sure where you pulled that from.

Comment: @VimalStan thats what i thought too. but apperantly that's not how it works. if i were to do it, i would do it that way as well.

Comment: @BoltClock The definition says "The :last-child selector matches every element that is the last child of its parent." I assumed that it would work the way I described. Thanks for the correction. Learnt something new today :)

Answer (score -1):

Related: [Using the last-child selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293369/using-last-child-in-css)

---

Any reason you don't want to use

```
.location {border:none;}
```

?

Comment: .location will change on every page, depends upon what the content is, so I cant use .location as selector

Comment: Check out the answer by @Branden-Silva in the SO link I've added, it should help you solve your problem.

Comment: I haven't problem with only IE, actually it's not working within all browsers