# CSS selector for first element inside class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this stuff

```
<div class="foo">
  <input type="text" name="bar" value="" />
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">foobar 1</a>
</div>
<div class="foo">
  <input type="text" name="bar" value="" />
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">foobar 2</a>
</div>
<div class="foo">
  <input type="text" name="bar" value="" />
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">foobar 3</a>
</div>

<!-- I'm trying with this CSS, but with no luck -->
<style> 
.foo a:first-child {
   display:none;
}
</style>
```

How can I only display `foobar 2` and `foobar 3` links?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The selector should select the first `.foo` element, not the first `a` within foo.

```
.foo:first-child a{
   display:none;
}
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543079/css-pseudo-class-last-child-issue/15543914#15543914) for more information on pseudo selectors as well as this [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/MH4LN/4/).

Answer (score 1):

You should move `:first-child` pseudo-class:

```
.foo:first-child a {
   display:none;
}
```

But it requires that `div` to be the first child of it's parent element.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PFUAh/1/)**

Answer (score -1):

So simple

```
$('.foo:nth-child(3)')
```