# How to get the last Element of CSS?

Tags: css

```css
.year-seperator:last-of-type {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="blog-year">  
    <li><a href="http://my.link">2016</a><span class="year-seperator">|</span></li>
    <li><a href="http://my.link">2015</a><span class="year-seperator">|</span></li>
    <li><a href="http://my.link">2014</a><span class="year-seperator">|</span></li>
    <li><a href="http://my.link">2013</a><span class="year-seperator">|</span></li>
</ul>
```

Then all the separator disappear. Why? How can I get the last element of that class? Or how can I hide it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the last-child selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293369/using-the-last-child-selector)

Comment: no dup bro. different question.

Comment: try now, it is working, i have made some changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they are all at last of li. It's the last li element not last span element. It should look like this:

```
li:last-child .year-seperator {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```css
.blog-year li:last-child .year-seperator {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="blog-year">  
    <li><a href="http://my.link">2016</a><span class="year-seperator">|</span></li>
    <li><a href="http://my.link">2015</a><span class="year-seperator">|</span></li>
    <li><a href="http://my.link">2014</a><span class="year-seperator">|</span></li>
    <li><a href="http://my.link">2013</a><span class="year-seperator">|</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Syntax**

```
element:last-child { style_properties }
```

Read More Details [Click](https://www.techonthenet.com/css/selectors/last_child.php)

```css
  .blog-year li .year-seperator:last-child
      {
         display:none; 
      }
```

```html
    <ul class="blog-year"> 
        <li><a href="http://my.link">2016</a><span class="year-seperator">|</span></li>
     <li><a href="http://my.link">2015</a><span class="year-seperator">|</span></li>
     <li><a href="http://my.link">2014</a><span class="year-seperator">|</span></li>
     <li><a href="http://my.link">2013</a><span class="year-seperator">|</span></li>
    </ul>
```