# Problem getting the last div with the last-of-type selector

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply some CSS to the last `.topic-wrapper` div (which is inside the `entry-content` div):

```
<div class="entry-content">

 <div class="bbp-pagination">
 <h2 class="dark-title">Top Topics</h2>
 <div class="topic-wrapper">
 <h4></h4>
 <div class="topic-wrapper">
 <h4></h4>
 <div class="topic-wrapper"> <!-- I'm trying to get this one -->
 <h4></h4>
 <div class="mainbar">
 <div class="bbp-pagination">
```

with this code: `.entry-content div:last-child`

But it seems like the CSS is being applied to some divs inside `.topic-wrapper`.

Like:

```
<div class="topic-wrapper">
<div class="topic-left">
<h2>
<span>
<span class="bbp-topic-started-in">
<div class="bbp-topic-tags"> <!-- this one -->
<p>
```

Any suggestions to solve this?

```
</div>
```

Comment: Don't know if this will help but there is a similar post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543513/getting-last-child-of-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, using ">" gets you just the direct descendents:

```
.entry-content > div:last-child
```

Here is an example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="outer">
    </div>
    <div class="outer">
    </div>
     <div class="outer">
    </div>
</div>



.container
{
    width:300px;

    background-color:yellow;
}

.outer
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    margin:20px;
}

.inner
{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:pink;
    margin:5px;
}



.container > div:last-child
{
    background-color:blue;
}

/* uncomment this statement to see the alternative broken version*/
/*
.container div:last-child
{
    background-color:green;
}

*/
```

You can view the [example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexkey/FdHyM/)

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm misreading your nesting you can't. `:last-child` finds elements that are the last child of their parents, but the last child of entry-content is `bbp-pagination`.

Additionally `.entry-content div:last-child` finds ALL divs that are descendants of `.entry-content` - NOT just the direct child.

You probably want `.entry-content>div:last-child` which looks only at immediate descendants. (i.e. children, but not grandchildren)

Comment: Yep :last-child and :first-child have terrible names.

Comment: Thanks, but its applying the CSS to all divs inside .entry-content. Is there any way of only applying the CSS to divs with the class `.topic-wrapper`?

Comment: Sure `.entry-content>div.topic-wrapper:last-child` Which means, look at the direct children of `.entry-content`, if the last one is a `div`, and it has the class `.topic-wrapper` select it. (If the last child is something else this rule will do nothing.) I hope you know this css selector will not work for IE based browsers. I assume you are using it for internal code only?

Comment: I finally decided to use the jQuery `.last` I guess it EVEN work in Internet Explorer.