# jQuery for selecting tags that have a certain immediate child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

How can I use jQuery to select all p tags that have at least one a tag as an immediate child?

For the document:

```
<div>
    <p><a>My Link</a></p>
    <p><div><a>My nested Link</a></div></p>
</div>
```

It would return only the first p tag.

Comment: Such a selector would return only the first `p` for the wrong reasons - a `p` cannot contain a `div` in HTML, even if you try to force it by creating the respective DOM elements directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>$('p:has(a)')</strike>

will do the trick.

http://jsfiddle.net/xKc8T/

**Update**

The issue with the `font` tag can be fixed like this:

```
$('p:has(a):not(:has(font))')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xKc8T/1/

**Update 2**

Okay scrap all that.  As per the comments the `:has()` filter doesn't just look at the direct children.  So how about we go the other way and select all `a` tags and then select the parent of those where the parent is a `p`.

```
$('a').parent('p')
```

or to avoid selecting all `a` tags you could do

```
$('p > a').parent()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xKc8T/3/

**Yet Another Update**

Thanks to @BoltClock for this suggestion.  The following syntax also works:

```
$('p:has(> a)')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xKc8T/4/

Comment: Technically this solves the problem, but in my case I discovered that the <font> tag throws jQuery. The following doc makes jQuery return both p tags:
<p><font><a>My Link</a></font></p>
<p><a>My Link 2</a></p>

Comment: The `:has` selector doesn't look only at direct children, but **any** descendant that matches that type of element. This only works in the example jsFiddle because putting a `<div>` inside a `<p>` is invalid HTML, and therefore the `<div>` (and its contents) are rendered **outside** of the `<p>`.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - thanks for the catch.  See my new update for another solution.

Comment: I hear that you can use any combinator with `:has()` so it will only look at whichever elements have that relationship, for example `p:has(> a)` should only check for `p` elements with `a` children. I find that syntax weird though, if it works. Especially seeing that it's undocumented.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're probably going to have to use `.filter()` to do this. The following code should do what you need:

```
$('p').filter(function() { return $(this).children('a').length > 0;});
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DrqzJ/1/)

EDIT: Modified the demo to include valid HTML (replaced the `<div>` with a `<span>` inside the second `<p>`).

Comment: See my answer for a more concise version using the filters built into the jQuery selectors

Answer (score 0):

<s>It's as easy as:</s>

```
$("div p:first-child")
```

You might want to consider applying an `id` or a `class` to the `div` to limit the DOM traversal to just the relevant `div` and `p` blocks.

[This answer is more or less the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543513/getting-last-child-of-div), just looking for the last child.

*UPDATE* Sorry, misread the 'first p tag' bit.

Try this:

```
$("div p:has(a)")
```

Comment: That's very specific to the HTML example in the question, and I don't think really answers the question.

Comment: Sorry, the I misread the reference to first p tag. I've updated my answer.